# How take a screenshot of whole webpage not only the visible portion

Tags: android, view, android-webview, screenshot

I found it from the internet but it just take screenshot of current view of a webview which is visible to the user but not the whole webpage which is loaded in the webview.Had someone gone through this problem ? Help plz

This is my code:

```
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.webView);
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

I have also used these methods but still i didn't get the screenshot of whole webview ...

```
            View v1 = wv.getRootView();
            View v1 = iv.getRootView(); 
            View v1 = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```